# Get all Data from ListView and Compare String in C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView in which there are two Columns.

Actually, I want to Get Data From my second Column and then Compare this with my hard Coded message.
E.g At this time, there is a name of Person at first Number in ListView and In Behind Coding, if i have that Specific Name then Count increase and Show me Message that Person Searched. 
In Simple words, I want to match the patterns.

It is noted that I am using ListView not GridTableView or Table.
And Sorry about my English, it is not well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the name from the selected row of the list view:

```
name = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```

If you want to select all results from second column:

```
foreach( ListViewItem item in listView1.Items )
{
    mess += item.SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much. One Question that If I want to Store that Column Data in Array then What I Do?
You have written "mess" which is String but If i want array there then?

Comment: @Crazyzoar bad luck, There doesn,t seem to exist conversion methods from listviewItems to array... You,ll have to do it manually.